# I've error in Google Colab notebook "so-vits-svc 4.0 inference FIXED thanks goat YeezyBeaver.ipynb"

Tags: numpy

I do not know much about programming in the code as a whole, and I tried to do everything according to the tutorial (there will be a link at the end of the question), as far as I understand there is a problem in NumPy(?), I would also like to see in your answers where and what to do.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
__init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf . Check the section C-API incompatibility at the Troubleshooting ImportError section at https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html#c-api-incompatibility for indications on how to solve this problem .

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d1e0a46a13b4> in <cell line: 15>()
     13 
     14 import torch
---> 15 from inference import infer_tool
     16 from inference import slicer
     17 from inference.infer_tool import Svc

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyworld/__init__.py in <module>
      5 __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution('pyworld').version
      6 
----> 7 from .pyworld import *

pyworld/pyworld.pyx in init pyworld.pyworld()

__init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Open Examples button](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb)

Here is the code from the problem cell, its maximum is zero seconds, although I managed to extend its operation for another 7 seconds thanks to `pip install -U numpy`

```
#@title Open the file explorer on the left of your screen and drag-and-drop an audio file anywhere. Then run the below cell.
import os
import glob
import json
import copy
import logging
import io
from ipywidgets import widgets
from pathlib import Path
from IPython.display import Audio, display

os.chdir('/content/so-vits-svc')

import torch
from inference import infer_tool
from inference import slicer
from inference.infer_tool import Svc
import soundfile
import numpy as np

MODELS_DIR = "models"

def get_speakers():
  speakers = []
  for _,dirs,_ in os.walk(MODELS_DIR):
    for folder in dirs:
      cur_speaker = {}
      # Look for G_****.pth
      g = glob.glob(os.path.join(MODELS_DIR,folder,'G_*.pth'))
      if not len(g):
        print("Skipping "+folder+", no G_*.pth")
        continue
      cur_speaker["model_path"] = g[0]
      cur_speaker["model_folder"] = folder

      # Look for *.pt (clustering model)
      clst = glob.glob(os.path.join(MODELS_DIR,folder,'*.pt'))
      if not len(clst):
        print("Note: No clustering model found for "+folder)
        cur_speaker["cluster_path"] = ""
      else:
        cur_speaker["cluster_path"] = clst[0]

      # Look for config.json
      cfg = glob.glob(os.path.join(MODELS_DIR,folder,'*.json'))
      if not len(cfg):
        print("Skipping "+folder+", no config json")
        continue
      cur_speaker["cfg_path"] = cfg[0]
      with open(cur_speaker["cfg_path"]) as f:
        try:
          cfg_json = json.loads(f.read())
        except Exception as e:
          print("Malformed config json in "+folder)
        for name, i in cfg_json["spk"].items():
          cur_speaker["name"] = name
          cur_speaker["id"] = i
          if not name.startswith('.'):
            speakers.append(copy.copy(cur_speaker))

    return sorted(speakers, key=lambda x:x["name"].lower())

logging.getLogger('numba').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
chunks_dict = infer_tool.read_temp("inference/chunks_temp.json")
existing_files = []
slice_db = -40
wav_format = 'wav'

class InferenceGui():
  def __init__(self):
    self.speakers = get_speakers()
    self.speaker_list = [x["name"] for x in self.speakers]
    self.speaker_box = widgets.Dropdown(
        options = self.speaker_list
    )
    display(self.speaker_box)

    def convert_cb(btn):
      self.convert()
    def clean_cb(btn):
      self.clean()

    self.convert_btn = widgets.Button(description="Convert")
    self.convert_btn.on_click(convert_cb)
    self.clean_btn = widgets.Button(description="Delete all audio files")
    self.clean_btn.on_click(clean_cb)

    self.trans_tx = widgets.IntText(value=0, description='Transpose')
    self.cluster_ratio_tx = widgets.FloatText(value=0.0, 
      description='Clustering Ratio')
    self.noise_scale_tx = widgets.FloatText(value=0.4, 
      description='Noise Scale')
    self.auto_pitch_ck = widgets.Checkbox(value=False, description=
      'Auto pitch f0 (do not use for singing)')

    display(self.trans_tx)
    display(self.cluster_ratio_tx)
    display(self.noise_scale_tx)
    display(self.auto_pitch_ck)
    display(self.convert_btn)
    display(self.clean_btn)

  def convert(self):
    trans = int(self.trans_tx.value)
    speaker = next(x for x in self.speakers if x["name"] == 
          self.speaker_box.value)
    spkpth2 = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),speaker["model_path"])
    print(spkpth2)
    print(os.path.exists(spkpth2))

    svc_model = Svc(speaker["model_path"], speaker["cfg_path"], 
      cluster_model_path=speaker["cluster_path"])
    
    input_filepaths = [f for f in glob.glob('/content/**/*.*', recursive=True)
     if f not in existing_files and 
     any(f.endswith(ex) for ex in ['.wav','.flac','.mp3','.ogg','.opus'])]
    for name in input_filepaths:
      print("Converting "+os.path.split(name)[-1])
      infer_tool.format_wav(name)

      wav_path = str(Path(name).with_suffix('.wav'))
      wav_name = Path(name).stem
      chunks = slicer.cut(wav_path, db_thresh=slice_db)
      audio_data, audio_sr = slicer.chunks2audio(wav_path, chunks)

      audio = []
      for (slice_tag, data) in audio_data:
          print(f'#=====segment start, '
              f'{round(len(data)/audio_sr, 3)}s======')
          
          length = int(np.ceil(len(data) / audio_sr *
              svc_model.target_sample))
          
          if slice_tag:
              print('jump empty segment')
              _audio = np.zeros(length)
          else:
              # Padding "fix" for noise
              pad_len = int(audio_sr * 0.5)
              data = np.concatenate([np.zeros([pad_len]),
                  data, np.zeros([pad_len])])
              raw_path = io.BytesIO()
              soundfile.write(raw_path, data, audio_sr, format="wav")
              raw_path.seek(0)
              _cluster_ratio = 0.0
              if speaker["cluster_path"] != "":
                _cluster_ratio = float(self.cluster_ratio_tx.value)
              out_audio, out_sr = svc_model.infer(
                  speaker["name"], trans, raw_path,
                  cluster_infer_ratio = _cluster_ratio,
                  auto_predict_f0 = bool(self.auto_pitch_ck.value),
                  noice_scale = float(self.noise_scale_tx.value))
              _audio = out_audio.cpu().numpy()
              pad_len = int(svc_model.target_sample * 0.5)
              _audio = _audio[pad_len:-pad_len]
          audio.extend(list(infer_tool.pad_array(_audio, length)))
          
      res_path = os.path.join('/content/',
          f'{wav_name}_{trans}_key_'
          f'{speaker["name"]}.{wav_format}')
      soundfile.write(res_path, audio, svc_model.target_sample,
          format=wav_format)
      display(Audio(res_path, autoplay=True)) # display audio file
    pass

  def clean(self):
     input_filepaths = [f for f in glob.glob('/content/**/*.*', recursive=True)
     if f not in existing_files and 
     any(f.endswith(ex) for ex in ['.wav','.flac','.mp3','.ogg','.opus'])]
     for f in input_filepaths:
       os.remove(f)

inference_gui = InferenceGui()
```

Now the topic with AI covers is popular, I tried to do everything according to the tutorial, but it turned out like this, I will be grateful for help.
[Tutorial (On Russian lang)](https://pikabu.ru/story/kak_sozdat_iikaver_s_pomoshchyu_neyroseti_generatsiya_nesushchestvuyushchikh_pesen_s_golosami_znamenityikh_artistov_10231004?ysclid=li1fg1thtb761607848#comments)